# Flutter Statefull Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Не раз читал что, не рекомендуется  использовать statefullWidget. Пример `BottomNavigationBar` с переключением страниц в `body`. Как можно обойтись без `statefullWidget` в этом примере? Использовать Bloc? Или же это касается только бизнес логики?

```
class HomeScreenTest extends StatefulWidget {

@override
  _HomeScreenTestState createState() => _HomeScreenTestState();
}

class _HomeScreenTestState extends State<HomeScreenTest> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final pages = [
    Page1(),
    Page2(),
    Page3(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: pages[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('pag1'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('page'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('page3'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) и вправду нельзя использовать везде, но для начала разберемся почему.

Когда мы вызываем [State.setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html), `StatefulWidget` начинает перестраиваться. При перестроении он удаляет элементы ниже его по *дереву* (вложенные chlid'ы), тем самым заставляя перестраивать все до конца *дерева виджетов*. Из-за этого перестроения забиваться [isolate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) в котором работает UI и происходит потребление ресурсов аппарата.

`StatefulWidget` можно **"безопасно"** использовать либо без `State.setState`. Либо в конце *дерева виджетов*, когда он не будет заставлять перестраиваться нижние виджеты.

---

Но отказаться от `State.setState` мы не можем, нам нужно динамический изменять UI, что для этого есть?

**State Management** - оптимизация перестроения UI. Их много и у всех разные подходы:

1. [Bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev) иммутабельное состояние на основе Stream, так называемый реактивный интерфейс.
2. [MobX](https://mobx.netlify.app/) мутабельное состояние с мутациями.
3. [Redux](https://pub.dev/packages/redux) иммутабельное глобальное состояние с однонаправленным потоком данных.
4. [И другие...](http://fluttersamples.com/)

**[Change Notifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html)** - уведомление виджетов о смене состоянии, для небольшого количества слушателей.

**[Persist Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorage-class.html)** - кеш UI, вместо того чтобы делать перестроение виджета мы можем показать его из кеша.

---

Так что использовать для `BottomNavigationBar` и подобных небольших задач?

Ответ: использовать Change Notifier (+ Persist Widget, если подходит под задачу). Для таких задач будет лишним использовать State Management. Вот пример как это можно сделать ([provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) использовал для удобства работы с `Change Notifier`):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Index()),
        ],
        child: BottomNavigationBarController(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Index with ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  get currentIndex => _currentIndex;

  void setIndex(int index) {
    _currentIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class BottomNavigationBarController extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> pages = [
    FirstPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('Page1'),
    ),
    SecondPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('Page2'),
    ),
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  Widget _bottomNavigationBar(BuildContext context, int selectedIndex) =>
      BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int index) => context.read<Index>().setIndex(index),
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            title: Text('First Page'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.list),
            title: Text('Second Page'),
          ),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar:
          _bottomNavigationBar(context, context.watch<Index>().currentIndex),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[context.watch<Index>().currentIndex],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('FirstPage'),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('SecondPage'),
    );
  }
}
```