# 1. Почему не выводятся данные из базы данных; 2. Почему в окне AddEmployee не работает валидатор (окно закрывается с пустыми данными формы)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Сразу прошу прощения, я только начал разбираться с flutter.
Вопроса 2:

1. Почему в main у меня в ListView не выводится выборка из базы данных? Если я выполню ее перед строительством виджета, у меня все получается... но этого мало, я хочу видеть изменения сразу же после добавления новой записи.
2. В файле addEmployee не работает валидатор формы, и я не могу понять, почему.
   Окно закрывается сразу же после нажатия кнопки "Добавить", хотелось бы, чтобы этого не происходило.

Файл main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'employees_instruments.dart';
import 'addEmployee.dart';

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  String dbName = "DataBase.db";

  runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Employees',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/':(BuildContext context) =>  MyHomePage('Employees', dbName),
        '/add':(BuildContext context) => AddEmployee(dbName)
      }
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String dbName;
  final String title;

  MyHomePage(this.title, this.dbName);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Employee> employees;
  int employeeNum = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getEmployees();
  }
  _getEmployees()async{
    setState(() async {
      employees = await MyDatabase.getEmployees(widget.dbName);
      employeeNum = employees.length;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        // Установить отступ 5 для top, bottom, left и right
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: _buildListItem, itemCount: employeeNum)
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/add');},
        tooltip: 'AddEmployee',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, int index){

    return Card(
          child: Row(children:[
             Column(children: [
                Text(employees[index].name,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                Text(employees[index].surname,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
             ],),
             Column(children: [
                Text("Возраст:",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                Text(employees[index].age.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),)
             ],)
      ]
    ));
  }
}
```

Файл addEmployee.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'employees_instruments.dart';

class AddEmployee extends StatelessWidget {
  final String _dbName;
  AddEmployee(this._dbName);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Добавить сотрудника")
        ),
        body: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: AddFormState(_dbName))
    );
  }
}
class AddFormState extends StatefulWidget{
  final String _dbName;
  AddFormState(this._dbName);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AddForm();
}
class _AddForm extends State<AddFormState>{
  // константа, позволяющая обращаться из дочерних элементов к функционалу формы для проверки данных, сохранения или сброса значений.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _name;
  String _surname;
  int _age;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Form(key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children:[
            Text("Имя"),
            TextFormField(validator: (value){
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return "Введите имя";
              }
              else{
                _name = value;
              }
            },),
            Text("Фамилия"),
            TextFormField(validator: (value){
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return "Введите фамилию";
              }
              else{
                _surname = value;
              }
            },),
            Text("Возраст"),
            TextFormField(validator: (value){
              if (value.isEmpty && _isNumeric(value)) {
                return "Введите возраст";
              }
              else{
                _age = int.tryParse(value);
              }
            },),
            SizedBox(height: 100.0,),
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  if(_formKey.currentState.validate())
                    await MyDatabase.addEmployee(widget._dbName, Employee(0, _name, _surname, _age));
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text("Добавить"), color: Colors.blue, textColor: Colors.white)
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
  // проверка, является ли строка числом
  bool _isNumeric(String str) {
    // tryParse преобразует строку в число. Если не получается, возвращает null
    return int.tryParse(str) != null;
  }
}
```

Файл employees_instruments.dart

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class Employee{
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String surname;
  final int age;
  Employee(this.id, this.name, this.surname, this.age);
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return{
      'name' : name,
      'surname' : surname,
      'age' : age
    };
  }
}
class MyDatabase{
  static Future<Database> getDatabase(String link) async {
    return openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), link),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        return db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE Employees(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, surname TEXT, age INTEGER) \n"
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> addEmployee(String link, Employee employee) async{
    final Database db = await getDatabase(link);
    await db.insert("Employees", employee.toMap(), conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,);
  }
  static Future<List<Employee>> getEmployees (String link)async {
    final Database db = await getDatabase(link);
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('Employees');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Employee(
          maps[i]["id"],
          maps[i]['name'],
          maps[i]['surname'],
          maps[i]['age']
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас просто банально нет триггера на обновления данных. Даже если вы добавляете данные, вы никак не говорите другим виджетам об этом.

- [Разница StatelessWidget и StatefulWidget](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1057725/261617)
- [Futures, Streams и Async/Await во Flutter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1013829/261617)
- [State Management](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1145686/261617)

---

```
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text 1';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.length < 2) {
                return 'Please enter some text 2';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  Scaffold.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```